# Region of no light after infinite reflection in a ellipse

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Let’s say you have a ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+ \frac{y^2}{b^2}=1 ,  |a|>|b|$ and you have a ray of light starting on a line $y=mx+c$ such that it intersects the ellipse twice and does not pass between the foci then after infinite reflections you will get a second ellipse like the following…

[image: credits to Alexander Gustafsson]

[video link](https://youtu.be/-VjbYI-eaTQ)

$\textbf{My Attempt}$

We can obviously solve the line equation and ellipse equation and we get

$$x = \frac{-a^2mc \pm ab\alpha}{a^2m^2+b^2}$$
$$y = \frac{b^2c \pm abm\alpha}{a^2m^2+b^2}$$

where $\alpha = \sqrt{a^2m^2+b^2-c^2}$

and then through a little bit of calculus and taking the starting point of ray as the negative signed solution of line and ellipse (another question here btw, is it necessary to check with positive signed solution too), we can find the angle of incidence

$$i = \arctan\left(\frac{ab^2mc+a^2m^2b\alpha -b^3\alpha+ab^2mc}{ab^2c+a^2bm\alpha+mb^3\alpha-ab^2m^2c}\right)$$

Now I am not getting how to proceed further, like how to enforce the conditions of not passing between the foci and even after finding that how to navigate through this mess of a equation and find the region of no light…

Comment: What you're observing are the so-called 'loop orbits' of elliptical billiards. See for instance the blog post [here](https://thatsmaths.com/2019/07/25/billiards-ballyards/) and the longer introductory paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.09295). I'll warn that the math is rather fearsome and assumes some background in analytical mechanics (Hamiltonian and Lagrangian).

Comment: The inner ellipse is confocal with the outer one and is tangent to all rays. A very simple geometrical proof can be found in Tabachnikov's book "Geometry and billiards", Theorem 4.4 (that proof is also reproduced here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3223176/why-are-these-angles-equal)

Comment: The last part of the proof is missing from the page linked above: it consists in proving that triangles $F_1'A_1F_2$ and $F_1A_1F_2'$ are congruent (easy).